# What is the time complexity of pandas' read_csv and display functions?

Tags: python, pandas, time-complexity

I'm writing a python code and using pandas' read_csv and display functions, the code must have O(n) time complexity, when using these two functions, assuming the the rest of the code doesn't exceed this complexity, and with the fact that these two functions are not in any loop, is their complexity more than O(n) ?

Thank you

Comment: First, ask yourself: "Why wouldn't it be O(n)?"

Answer (score 0):

They are both O(n), where n is the length of the input.